Как автоматически заполнять табличную часть при выборе элемента из справочника?
Я разрабатываю справочник в 1С, у которого есть ряд реквизитов и табличная часть. В табличную часть я хочу добавлять другой экземпляр справочника, и чтобы остальные поля заполнялись автоматически. То есть данные подтягивались из реквизитов выбранного справочника.
Если приводить упрощенный пример, я хочу сделать следующее:
В табличной части я выбираю помещение, а площадь подтягивается из реквизитов справочника.


Как называется справочник? Данные реквизита "Площадь" точно нужно в него дублировать (хранить) или нужно чтобы просто оно справочно отображалось?!

справочник называется помещение, их нужно дублировать (хранить) для последующих использований

Вообще странно. Это настоящая или учебная задача? Где потом собираетесь использовать эту площадь? Если она уже заполнена, то почему потом её не получать от выбранной ссылки? Не понимаю, зачем дублировать хранимые данные.

Для того, чтобы автоматически заполнять табличную часть при выборе элемента из справочника. Можно воспользоваться следующим механизмом, выбрать событие "при изменении" поля "Название", сделать запрос к интересующему справочнику, выбрать необходимые реквизиты и заполнить поля, например поле "Площадь"

Я правильно понимаю, что это будет написано на функциональном языке 1С? Как примерно будет выглядеть этот запрос?

@L0RD_V0R0N Да, это будет на языке 1С. Запрос будет выглядеть стандартно, Выбрать необходимые поля Из Справочника где находятся данные, по условию Где поле соответствует запрашиваемым данным.
